# Serialize form data of a certain form out ot many, if a certain field has value jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a page with a couple of forms (number is different, as they are loaded dynamically). I am able to cycle through every form on the page and serialize its data to send to my server. I was wondering if it's possible to only serialize/add data to the array only if a checkbox in any given form is ticked (and that gives it a value I need to use)?
Here is my code:

**Javascript**

```
$('body').on('click', '.saveStates', function () {
    $('.states_list').each(function (key, value) {
            forms.push($(this).serialize());
    });
```

**HTML**

```
   <form class="states_list">
    <input type="checkbox" class="selected_state" name="active_state" value="<?php echo $state['id']; ?>"
    <input type="text" class="col-md-10" name="pdf_price" id="pdf_price" value="<?php echo $state['pdf_price']; ?>">
    </form>
<button type="button" class="saveStates btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

I need to check if the checkbox with class `selected-state` has a value (is ticked), and then add that form to the `forms` array. I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
$('.states_list').each(function (key, value) {
    if($('.selected_state').val()){
        forms.push($(this).serialize());
}
});
```

But that does not work.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: try $('.selected_state').is(":checked") instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter it using [.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/):

```
$('body').on('click', '.saveStates', function() {
  $('.states_list').has('.selected_state:checked').each(function(key, value) {
    forms.push($(this).serialize());
  });
});
```

But you code could just be:

```
$('body').on('click', '.saveStates', function() {
  var forms = $('.states_list').has('.selected_state:checked').serializeArray();
  console.log(forms)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick. The first option is better for my use case, as I get an array of every single form, rather than a string of all the fields.

Comment: @MihailIvanchev I just updated second one, using `serializeArray()` which returns an array of objects

Comment: Thanks, but just a bunch of arrays is better, because I can parse them in the back end with `parse_str()` in a `foreach` cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get the issue.

If you only need to check whether the checkbox has been checked in order to send the form you could
`if ($(this).is(":checked")) forms.push($(this).serialize());`

Comment: `this` refers to the `form` element regarding OP's code

Comment: My bad ($(this).is(":checked")) . THIS here refers to the current targeted checkbox, while the second THIS is taken directly from the OPs code